# Batch file script to remove special characters from filenames (Windows)

Tags: windows, batch-file, filenames, gnupg, file-rename

I have a large set of files, some of which contain special characters in the filename (e.g. ä,ö,%, and others). I'd like a script file to iterate over these files and rename them removing the special characters. I don't really mind what it does, but it could replace them with underscores for example e.g.

Störung%20.doc would be renamed to St_rung_20.doc

In order of preference:

1. A Windiws batch file
2. A Windows script file to run with cscript (vbs)
3. A third party piece of software that can be run from the command-line (i.e. no user interaction required)
4. Another language script file, for which I'd have to install an additional script engine

Background: I'm trying to encrypt these file with GnuPG on Windows but it doesn't seem to handle special characters in filenames with the --encrypt-files option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Tomalak who actually pointed me in the right direction. Thought I'd post here for completeness.

The problem seems to be that the codepage used by GPG is fixed (Latin I) independent of the codepage configured in the console. But once he pointed this out, I figured out how to workaraound this.

The trick is to change the codepage before generating the file list. This will actually make the filelist appear to be incorrect when viewed in the console. However, when passed to GPG, it works fine. GPG accepts the files and spits out the encrytped files with correct filenames.

The batch file looks something like this:

```
chcp 1252
dir /b /s /a-d MyFolder >filelist.txt
gpg -r test@test.com --encrypt-files <filelist.txt
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.
The question asked the a batch file, this questiomn obvioly solves the askers proble, (as you are the asker) but you shouldn't have selected this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried setting cmd.exe into another codepage before you feed the file names to gnupg? Issue `chcp 65001` to set cmd.exe to Unicode beforehand and try again.

If that fails, the following VBScript would do it:

```vb
Option Explicit

Dim fso: Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim invalidChars: Set invalidChars = New RegExp

' put all characters that you want to strip inside the brackets
invalidChars.Pattern =  "[äöüß&%]"
invalidChars.IgnoreCase = True
invalidChars.Global = True

If WScript.Arguments.Unnamed.Count = 0 Then
  WScript.Echo "Please give folder name as argument 1."
  WScript.Quit 1
End If

Recurse fso.GetFolder(WScript.Arguments.Unnamed(0))

Sub Recurse(f)
  Dim item

  For Each item In f.SubFolders
    Recurse item
    Sanitize item
  Next
  For Each item In f.Files
    Sanitize item
  Next
End Sub

Sub Sanitize(folderOrFile)
  Dim newName: newName = invalidChars.Replace(folderOrFile.Name, "_")
  If folderOrFile.Name = newName Then Exit Sub
  WScript.Echo folderOrFile.Name, " -> ", newName
  folderOrFile.Name = newName 
End Sub
```

call it like this:

```
cscript replace.vbs "c:\path\to\my\files"
```

You can also drag&drop a folder onto it in Windows Explorer.

Answer (score 3):

From http://www.robvanderwoude.com/bht.html:

use NT's SET's string substitution to replace or remove characters anywhere in a string:

```
SET STRING=[ABCDEFG]
SET STRING=%STRING:[=%
SET STRING=%STRING:]=%
ECHO String: %STRING%

will display 
String: ABCDEFG

SET STRING=[ABCDEFG]
SET STRING=%STRING:[=(%
SET STRING=%STRING:]=)%
ECHO String: %STRING%

will display 
String: (ABCDEFG)

SET STRING=[ABCDEFG]
SET STRING=%STRING:~1,7%
ECHO String: %STRING%

will display 
String: ABCDEFG
```

If you use this attempt, you will have to process each character you want to replace (e.g. Ä,Ö,Ü,ä,ö,ü,ß, but also á,à,é,è...) seperately.

Answer (score 2):

Following 'RenameFilesWithAccentedAndDiacriticalLatinChars.pl' PERL script renames files with accented and diacritical Latin characters :

- This PERL script starts from the folder given in parameter, or else from
  the current folder.
- It recursively searches for files with characters belonging to 80 - FF of
  CP 1250, CP 1252, CP 1254 and CP 1257 (mostly accented Latin characters)
  or Latin characters having diacritical marks.
- It calculates new file names by removing the accents and diacritical marks
  only from Latin characters  (For example,  Été --> Ete).
- It displays all proposed renaming and perhaps conflicts, and asks the user
  for global approval.
- If the user has approved, it renames all files having no conflict.

Option '--batch' avoids interactive questions.  Use with care.

Option '--'      avoids the next parameter to be interpreted as option.

**Special Warning** :

- This script was originally encoded in UTF-8, and should stay so.
- This script may rename a lot of files.
- Files names are theoretically all encoded only with UTF-8.  But some file
  names may be found to contain also some characters having legacy encoding.
- The author has applied efforts for consistency checks, robustness, conflict
  detection and use of appropriate encoding.
  So this script should only rename files by removing accents and diacritical
  marks from Latin characters.
- But this script has been tested only under a limited number of OS
  (Windows, Mac OS X, Linux) and a limited number of terminal encodings
  (CP 850, ISO-8859-1, UTF-8).
- So, under weird circumstances, this script could rename many files with
  random names.
- Therefore, this script should be used with care, and modified with extreme
  care (beware encoding of internal strings, inputs, outputs and commands)

`````
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
#=============================================================================
#
#  Copyright 2010  Etienne URBAH
#
#  This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
#  it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.
#
#  This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
#  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
#  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
#  GNU General Public License for more details at
#  http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
#
#  For usage and SPECIAL WARNING, see the 'Help' section below.
#
#=============================================================================
use 5.008_000;    #  For correct Unicode support
use warnings;
use strict;
use Encode;

$| = 1;           #  Autoflush STDOUT

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#  Function ucRemoveEolUnderscoreDash :
#  Set Uppercase, remove End of line, Underscores and Dashes
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
sub ucRemoveEolUnderscoreDash
{
  local $_ = uc($_[0]);
  chomp;
  tr/_\-//d;
  $_;
}

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#  Constants
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
my $Encoding_Western  = 'ISO-8859-1';
my $Encoding_Central  = 'ISO-8859-2';
my $Encoding_Baltic   = 'ISO-8859-4';
my $Encoding_Turkish  = 'ISO-8859-9';
my $Encoding_W_Euro   = 'ISO-8859-15';
my $Code_Page_OldWest =   850;
my $Code_Page_Central =  1250;
my $Code_Page_Western =  1252;
my $Code_Page_Turkish =  1254;
my $Code_Page_Baltic  =  1257;
my $Code_Page_UTF8    = 65001;

my $HighBitSetChars   = pack('C*', 0x80..0xFF);

my %SuperEncodings    =
  ( &ucRemoveEolUnderscoreDash($Encoding_Western), 'cp'.$Code_Page_Western,
    &ucRemoveEolUnderscoreDash($Encoding_Central), 'cp'.$Code_Page_Central,
    &ucRemoveEolUnderscoreDash($Encoding_Baltic),  'cp'.$Code_Page_Baltic,
    &ucRemoveEolUnderscoreDash($Encoding_Turkish), 'cp'.$Code_Page_Turkish,
    &ucRemoveEolUnderscoreDash($Encoding_W_Euro),  'cp'.$Code_Page_Western,
    &ucRemoveEolUnderscoreDash('cp'.$Code_Page_OldWest),
                                                   'cp'.$Code_Page_Western );

my %EncodingNames     = ( 'cp'.$Code_Page_Central, 'Central European',
                          'cp'.$Code_Page_Western, 'Western European',
                          'cp'.$Code_Page_Turkish, '    Turkish     ',
                          'cp'.$Code_Page_Baltic,  '     Baltic     ' );

my %NonAccenChars     = ( 
                          #--------------------------------#
'cp'.$Code_Page_Central,  #   Central European (cp1250)    #
                          #--------------------------------#
                          #€_‚_„…†‡_‰Š‹ŚŤŽŹ_‘’“”•–—_™š›śťžź#
                          'E_,_,.++_%S_STZZ_````.--_Ts_stzz'.

                          # ˇ˘Ł¤Ą¦§¨©Ş«¬­®Ż°±˛ł´µ¶·¸ąş»Ľ˝ľż#
                          '_``LoAlS`CS_--RZ`+,l`uP.,as_L~lz'.

                          #ŔÁÂĂÄĹĆÇČÉĘËĚÍÎĎĐŃŇÓÔŐÖ×ŘŮÚŰÜÝŢß#
                          'RAAAALCCCEEEEIIDDNNOOOOxRUUUUYTS'.

                          #ŕáâăäĺćçčéęëěíîďđńňóôőö÷řůúűüýţ˙#
                          'raaaalccceeeeiiddnnoooo%ruuuuyt`',

                          #--------------------------------#
'cp'.$Code_Page_Western,  #   Western European  (cp1252)   #
                          #--------------------------------#
                          #€_‚ƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š‹Œ_Ž__‘’“”•–—˜™š›œ_žŸ#
                          'E_,f,.++^%S_O_Z__````.--~Ts_o_zY'.

                          # ¡¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª«¬­®¯°±²³´µ¶·¸¹º»¼½¾¿#
                          '_!cLoYlS`Ca_--R-`+23`uP.,10_qh3_'.

                          #ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚÛÜÝÞß#
                          'AAAAAAACEEEEIIIIDNOOOOOxOUUUUYTS'.

                          #àáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõö÷øùúûüýþÿ#
                          'aaaaaaaceeeeiiiidnooooo%ouuuuyty',

                          #--------------------------------#
'cp'.$Code_Page_Turkish,  #       Turkish  (cp1254)        #
                          #--------------------------------#
                          #€_‚ƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š‹Œ____‘’“”•–—˜™š›œ__Ÿ#
                          'E_,f,.++^%S_O____````.--~Ts_o__Y'.

                          # ¡¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª«¬­®¯°±²³´µ¶·¸¹º»¼½¾¿#
                          '_!cLoYlS`Ca_--R-`+23`uP.,10_qh3_'.

                          #ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏĞÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚÛÜİŞß#
                          'AAAAAAACEEEEIIIIGNOOOOOxOUUUUISS'.

                          #àáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïğñòóôõö÷øùúûüışÿ#
                          'aaaaaaaceeeeiiiignooooo%ouuuuisy',

                          #--------------------------------#
'cp'.$Code_Page_Baltic,   #       Baltic   (cp1257)        #
                          #--------------------------------#
                          #€_‚_„…†‡_‰_‹_¨ˇ¸_‘’“”•–—_™_›_¯˛_#
                          'E_,_,.++_%___``,_````.--_T___-,_'.

                          # �¢£¤�¦§Ø©Ŗ«¬­®Æ°±²³´µ¶·ø¹ŗ»¼½¾æ#
                          '__cLo_lSOCR_--RA`+23`uP.o1r_qh3a'.

                          #ĄĮĀĆÄÅĘĒČÉŹĖĢĶĪĻŠŃŅÓŌÕÖ×ŲŁŚŪÜŻŽß#
                          'AIACAAEECEZEGKILSNNOOOOxULSUUZZS'.

                          #ąįāćäåęēčéźėģķīļšńņóōõö÷ųłśūüżž˙#
                          'aiacaaeecezegkilsnnoooo%ulsuuzz`' );

my %AccentedChars;
my $AccentedChars     = '';
my $NonAccenChars     = '';
for ( $Code_Page_Central, $Code_Page_Western,
      $Code_Page_Turkish, $Code_Page_Baltic )
    {
      $AccentedChars{'cp'.$_}  = decode('cp'.$_, $HighBitSetChars);
      $AccentedChars          .= $AccentedChars{'cp'.$_};
      $NonAccenChars          .= $NonAccenChars{'cp'.$_};
    }
#print "\n", length($NonAccenChars), '  ', $NonAccenChars,"\n";
#print "\n", length($AccentedChars), '  ', $AccentedChars,"\n";

my $QuotedMetaNonAccenChars = quotemeta($NonAccenChars);

my $DiacriticalChars  = '';
for  ( 0x0300..0x036F, 0x1DC0..0x1DFF )
     { $DiacriticalChars .= chr($_) }

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#  Parse options and parameters
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
my $b_Help        = 0;
my $b_Interactive = 1;
my $b_UTF8        = 0;
my $b_Parameter   = 0;
my $Folder;

for  ( @ARGV )
{
  if    ( lc($_) eq '--' )
        { $b_Parameter = 1 }
  elsif ( (not $b_Parameter) and (lc($_) eq '--batch') )
        { $b_Interactive = 0 }
  elsif ( (not $b_Parameter) and (lc($_) eq '--utf8') )
        { $b_UTF8 = 1 }
  elsif ( $b_Parameter or (substr($_, 0, 1) ne '-') )
        {
          if  ( defined($Folder) )
              { die "$0 accepts only 1 parameter\n" }
          else
              { $Folder = $_ }
        }
  else
        { $b_Help = 1 }
}

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#  Help
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
if  ( $b_Help )
    {
      die << "END_OF_HELP"

$0  [--help]  [--batch]  [--]  [folder]

This script renames files with accented and diacritical Latin characters :

-  This PERL script starts from the folder given in parameter, or else from
   the current folder.
-  It recursively searches for files with characters belonging to 80 - FF of
   CP 1250, CP 1252, CP 1254 and CP 1257 (mostly accented Latin characters)
   or Latin characters having diacritical marks.
-  It calculates new file names by removing the accents and diacritical marks
   only from Latin characters  (For example,  Été --> Ete).
-  It displays all proposed renaming and perhaps conflicts, and asks the user
   for global approval.
-  If the user has approved, it renames all files having no conflict.

Option '--batch' avoids interactive questions.  Use with care.

Option '--'      avoids the next parameter to be interpreted as option.

SPECIAL WARNING :
-  This script was originally encoded in UTF-8, and should stay so.
-  This script may rename a lot of files.
-  Files names are theoretically all encoded only with UTF-8.  But some file
   names may be found to contain also some characters having legacy encoding.
-  The author has applied efforts for consistency checks, robustness, conflict
   detection and use of appropriate encoding.
   So this script should only rename files by removing accents and diacritical
   marks from Latin characters.
-  But this script has been tested only under a limited number of OS
   (Windows, Mac OS X, Linux) and a limited number of terminal encodings
   (CP 850, ISO-8859-1, UTF-8).
-  So, under weird circumstances, this script could rename many files with
   random names.
-  Therefore, this script should be used with care, and modified with extreme
   care (beware encoding of internal strings, inputs, outputs and commands)
END_OF_HELP
    }

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#  If requested, change current folder
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
if  ( defined($Folder) )
    { chdir($Folder)  or  die  "Can NOT set '$Folder' as current folder\n" }

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#  Following instruction is MANDATORY.
#  The return value should be non-zero, but on some systems it is zero.
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
utf8::decode($AccentedChars);
#  or  die "$0: '\$AccentedChars' should be UTF-8 but is NOT.\n";

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#  Check consistency on 'tr'
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
$_ = $AccentedChars;
eval "tr/$AccentedChars/$QuotedMetaNonAccenChars/";
if  ( $@ )  { warn $@ }
if  ( $@ or ($_ ne $NonAccenChars) )
    { die "$0: Consistency check on 'tr' FAILED :\n\n",
          "Translated Accented Chars :  ", length($_), ' :  ', $_, "\n\n",
          "       Non Accented Chars :  ", length($NonAccenChars), ' :  ',
          $NonAccenChars, "\n" }

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#  Constants depending on the OS
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
my $b_Windows = ( defined($ENV{'OS'}) and ($ENV{'OS'} eq 'Windows_NT') );

my ($Q, $sep, $sep2, $HOME, $Find, @List, $cwd, @Move);

if  ( $b_Windows )
    {
      $Q    = '"';
      $sep  = '\\';
      $sep2 = '\\\\';
      $HOME = $ENV{'USERPROFILE'};
      $Find = 'dir /b /s';
      @List = ( ( (`ver 2>&1` =~ m/version\s+([0-9]+)/i) and ($1 >= 6) ) ?
                ('icacls') :
                ( 'cacls') );
      $cwd  = `cd`;  chomp $cwd;  $cwd = quotemeta($cwd);
      @Move = ('move');
    }
else
    {
      $Q    = "'";
      $sep  = '/';
      $sep2 = '/';
      $HOME = $ENV{'HOME'};
      $Find = 'find .';
      @List = ('ls', '-d', '--');
      @Move = ('mv', '--');
      if  ( -w '/bin' )  { die "$0: For safety reasons, ",
                               "usage is BLOCKED to administrators.\n"}
    }

my $Encoding;
my $ucEncoding;
my $InputPipe = '-|';                                # Used as global variable

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#  Under Windows, associate input and output encodings to code pages :
#  -  Get the original code page,
#  -  If it is not UTF-8, try to set it to UTF-8,
#  -  Define the input encoding as the one associated to the ACTIVE code page,
#  -  If STDOUT is the console, encode output for the ORIGINAL code page.
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
my $Code_Page_Original;
my $Code_Page_Active;

if  ( $b_Windows )
    {
      #-----------------------------------------------------------------------
      #  Get the original code page
      #-----------------------------------------------------------------------
      $_ = `chcp`;
      m/([0-9]+)$/  or  die "Non numeric Windows code page :  ", $_;
      $Code_Page_Original = $1;
      print 'Windows Original Code Page = ', $Code_Page_Original,
            ( $Code_Page_Original == $Code_Page_UTF8 ?
              ' = UTF-8, display is perhaps correct with a true type font.' :
              '' ), "\n\n";
      $Code_Page_Active = $Code_Page_Original ;

      #-----------------------------------------------------------------------
      #  The input encoding must be the same as the ACTIVE code page
      #-----------------------------------------------------------------------
      $Encoding = ( $Code_Page_Active == $Code_Page_UTF8 ?
                    'utf8' :
                    'cp'.$Code_Page_Active ) ;
      $InputPipe .= ":encoding($Encoding)";
      print "InputPipe = '$InputPipe'\n\n";

      #-----------------------------------------------------------------------
      #  If STDOUT is the console, output encoding must be the same as the
      #  ORIGINAL code page
      #-----------------------------------------------------------------------
      if  ( $Code_Page_Original != $Code_Page_UTF8 )
          {
            no  warnings  'unopened';
            @_ = stat(STDOUT);
            use warnings;
            if  ( scalar(@_) and ($_[0] == 1) )
                { binmode(STDOUT, ":encoding(cp$Code_Page_Original)") }
            else
                { binmode(STDOUT, ":encoding($Encoding)") }
          }
    }

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#  Under *nix, if the 'LANG' environment variable contains an encoding,
#  verify that this encoding is supported by the OS and by PERL.
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
elsif ( defined($ENV{'LANG'}) and ($ENV{'LANG'} =~ m/\.([^\@]+)$/i) )
      {
        $Encoding = $1;

        my $Kernel = `uname -s`;
        chomp $Kernel;
        my $ucEncoding = &ucRemoveEolUnderscoreDash($Encoding);
        if  ( (lc($Kernel) ne 'darwin') and not grep {$_ eq $ucEncoding}
                       ( map { ($_, &ucRemoveEolUnderscoreDash($_)) }
                         `locale -m` ) )
            { die "Encoding = '$Encoding' or '$ucEncoding'  NOT supported ".
                  "by the OS\n" }

        my $ucLocale = &ucRemoveEolUnderscoreDash($ENV{'LANG'});
        if  ( not grep {$_ eq $ucLocale}
                       ( map { ($_, &ucRemoveEolUnderscoreDash($_)) }
                         `locale -a` ) )
            { die "Locale = '$ENV{LANG}' or '$ucLocale'  NOT supported ".
                  "by the OS\n" }

        if  ( not defined(Encode::find_encoding($Encoding)) )
            { die "Encoding = '$Encoding' or '$ucEncoding'  NOT supported ".
                  "by PERL\n" }

        print "Encoding = '$Encoding'  is supported by the OS and PERL\n\n";
        binmode(STDOUT, ":encoding($Encoding)");
      }

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#  Check consistency between parameter of 'echo' and output of 'echo'
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
undef $_;
if  ( defined($Encoding)  )
    {
      $ucEncoding = &ucRemoveEolUnderscoreDash($Encoding);
      if    ( defined($SuperEncodings{$ucEncoding}) )
            { $_ = substr($AccentedChars{$SuperEncodings{$ucEncoding}},
                          0x20, 0x60) }
      elsif ( defined($AccentedChars{$Encoding}) )
            { $_ = $AccentedChars{$Encoding} }
      elsif ( $Encoding =~ m/^utf-?8$/i )
            { $_ = $AccentedChars }
    }
if  ( not defined($_) )                # Chosen chars are same in 4 code pages
    { $_ = decode('cp'.$Code_Page_Central,
                  pack('C*', 0xC9, 0xD3, 0xD7, 0xDC,                    # ÉÓ×Ü
                             0xE9, 0xF3, 0xF7, 0xFC)) }                 # éó÷ü
#print  $_, "  (Parameter)\n\n";
#system 'echo', $_;
utf8::decode($_);
#print  "\n", $_, "  (Parameter after utf8::decode)\n\n";
my @EchoCommand = ( $b_Windows ?
                    "echo $_" :
                    ('echo', $_) );
#system @EchoCommand;

open(ECHO, $InputPipe, @EchoCommand)  or  die 'echo $_: ', $!;
my $Output = join('', <ECHO>);
close(ECHO);
chomp $Output;
#print "\n", $Output, "  (Output of 'echo')\n";
utf8::decode($Output);
#print "\n", $Output, "  (Output of 'echo' after utf8::decode)\n\n";

if  ( $Output ne $_ )
    {
      warn "$0: Consistency check between parameter ",
                         "of 'echo' and output of 'echo' FAILED :\n\n",
           "Parameter of 'echo' :  ", length($_), ' :  ', $_, "\n\n",
           "   Output of 'echo' :  ", length($Output), ' :  ', $Output, "\n";
      exit 1;
    }

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#  Print the translation table
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
if  ( defined($Encoding) )
{
  undef $_;
  $ucEncoding = &ucRemoveEolUnderscoreDash($Encoding);
  if    ( defined($SuperEncodings{$ucEncoding}) )
        {
          $_ = $SuperEncodings{$ucEncoding};
          print "--------- $EncodingNames{$_} ---------\n",
                '    ', substr($AccentedChars{$_}, 0x20, 0x20), "\n",
                '--> ', substr($NonAccenChars{$_}, 0x20, 0x20), "\n\n",
                '    ', substr($AccentedChars{$_}, 0x40, 0x20), "\n",
                '--> ', substr($NonAccenChars{$_}, 0x40, 0x20), "\n\n",
                '    ', substr($AccentedChars{$_}, 0x60, 0x20), "\n",
                '--> ', substr($NonAccenChars{$_}, 0x60, 0x20), "\n\n" }
  else
  {
    for ( 'cp'.$Code_Page_Central, 'cp'.$Code_Page_Western,
          'cp'.$Code_Page_Turkish, 'cp'.$Code_Page_Baltic )
    {
      if  ( ('cp'.$Encoding eq $_) or ($Encoding =~ m/^utf-?8$/i) )
          { print "--------- $EncodingNames{$_} ---------\n",
                  '    ', substr($AccentedChars{$_},    0, 0x20), "\n",
                  '--> ', substr($NonAccenChars{$_},    0, 0x20), "\n\n",
                  '    ', substr($AccentedChars{$_}, 0x20, 0x20), "\n",
                  '--> ', substr($NonAccenChars{$_}, 0x20, 0x20), "\n\n",
                  '    ', substr($AccentedChars{$_}, 0x40, 0x20), "\n",
                  '--> ', substr($NonAccenChars{$_}, 0x40, 0x20), "\n\n",
                  '    ', substr($AccentedChars{$_}, 0x60, 0x20), "\n",
                  '--> ', substr($NonAccenChars{$_}, 0x60, 0x20), "\n\n" }
    }
  }
}

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#  Completely optional :
#  Inside the Unison file, find the accented file names to ignore
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
my $UnisonFile = $HOME.$sep.'.unison'.$sep.'common.unison';
my @Ignores;

if  ( open(UnisonFile, '<', $UnisonFile) )
    {
      print "\nUnison File '", $UnisonFile, "'\n";
      while  ( <UnisonFile> )
      {
        if  ( m/^\s*ignore\s*=\s*Name\s*(.+)/ )
            {
              $_ = $1 ;
              if  ( m/[$AccentedChars]/ )
                  { push(@Ignores, $_) }
            }
      }
      close(UnisonFile);
    }
print map("  Ignore: ".$_."\n", @Ignores);

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#  Function OutputAndErrorFromCommand :
#
#  Execute the command given as array in parameter, and return STDOUT + STDERR
#
#  Reads global variable $InputPipe
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
sub OutputAndErrorFromCommand
{
  local $_;
  my @Command = @_;             # Protects content of @_ from any modification
  #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  #  Under Windows, fork fails, so :
  #  -  Enclose into double quotes parameters containing blanks or simple
  #     quotes,
  #  -  Use piped open with redirection of STDERR.
  #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  if  ( defined($ENV{'OS'}) and ($ENV{'OS'} eq 'Windows_NT') )
      {
        for  ( @Command )
             { s/^((-|.*(\s|')).*)$/$Q$1$Q/ }
        my $Command = join('  ', @Command);
        #print "\n", $Command;
        open(COMMAND, $InputPipe, "$Command  2>&1")  or  die '$Command: ', $!;
      }
  #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  #  Under Unix, quoting is too difficult, but fork succeeds
  #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  else
      {
        my $pid = open(COMMAND, $InputPipe);
        defined($pid) or die "Can't fork: $!";
        if  ( $pid == 0 )                           #  Child process
            {
              open STDERR, '>&=STDOUT';
              exec @Command;                        #  Returns only on failure
              die "Can't @Command";
            }
      }
  $_ = join('', <COMMAND>);                         #  Child's STDOUT + STDERR
  close COMMAND;
  chomp;
  utf8::decode($_);
  $_;
}

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#  Find recursively all files inside the current folder.
#  Verify accessibility of files with accented names.
#  Calculate non-accented file names from accented file names.
#  Build the list of duplicates.
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
my %Olds;                                # $Olds{$New} = [ $Old1, $Old2, ... ]
my $Old;
my $Dir;
my $Command;
my $ErrorMessage;
my $New;
my %News;

print "\n\nFiles with accented name and the corresponding non-accented name ",
      ":\n";

open(FIND, $InputPipe, $Find)  or  die $Find, ': ', $!;

FILE:
while  ( <FIND> )
{
  chomp;
  #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  #  If the file path contains UTF-8, following instruction is MANDATORY.
  #  If the file path does NOT contain UTF-8, it should NOT hurt.
  #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  utf8::decode($_);

  if  ( $b_Windows )
      { s/^$cwd$sep2// }
  else
      { s/^\.$sep2// }

  #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  #  From now on :  $_ = Dir/OldFilename
  #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  push(@{$Olds{$_}}, $_);

  if  ( m/([^$sep2]+)$/ and
        ($1 =~ m/[$AccentedChars]|([\ -\~][$DiacriticalChars])/) )
      {
        if  ( $b_Windows and m/$Q/ )
            {
              print "\n    $Q$_$Q\n***  contains quotes.\n";
              next;
            }
        for  my $Ignore  ( @Ignores )
        {
          if  ( m/$Ignore$/ )
              { next FILE }
        }
        $Old = $_ ;
        m/^(.*$sep2)?([^$sep2]+)$/;
        $Dir = ( defined($1) ? $1 : '');
        $_   = $2;

        #---------------------------------------------------------------------
        #  From now on :  $Old = Dir/OldFilename
        #                 $_   = OldFilename
        #---------------------------------------------------------------------
        print "\n    $Q$Old$Q\n";
        $ErrorMessage = &OutputAndErrorFromCommand(@List, $Old);
        if  ( $? != 0 )
            { print "*** $ErrorMessage\n" }
        else
            {
              #---------------------------------------------------------------
              #  Change accented Latin chars to non-accented chars.
              #  Remove all diacritical marks after Latin chars.
              #---------------------------------------------------------------
              eval "tr/$AccentedChars/$QuotedMetaNonAccenChars/";
              s/([\ -\~])[$DiacriticalChars]+/$1/g;
              #---------------------------------------------------------------
              #  From now on :  $Old = Dir/OldFilename
              #                 $_   = NewFilename
              #---------------------------------------------------------------
              if  ( $@ )
                  { warn $@ }
              else
                  {
                    $New = $Dir.$_;
                    if  ( $b_Windows or (not utf8::is_utf8($Dir)) )    # Weird
                        { utf8::decode($New) }                 # but necessary
                    $News{$Old} = $New;
                    push(@{$Olds{$New}}, $Old);
                  }
              print "--> $Q$Dir$_$Q\n";
            }
      }
}

close(FIND);

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#  Print list of duplicate non-accented file names
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
my $b_NoDuplicate = 1;

for  my $New  ( sort keys %Olds )
{
  if  ( scalar(@{$Olds{$New}}) > 1 )
      {
        if  ( $b_NoDuplicate )
            {
              print "\n\nFollowing files would have same non-accented name ",
                    ":\n";
              $b_NoDuplicate = 0;
            }
        print "\n", map('    '.$_."\n", @{$Olds{$New}}), '--> ', $New, "\n";
        for  ( @{$Olds{$New}} )
             { delete $News{$_} };
      }
}

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#  If there are NO file to rename, then exit
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
my $Number = scalar(keys %News);

print "\n\n";
if  ( $Number < 1 )
    {
      print "There are NO file to rename\n";
      exit;
    }

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#  Ask the user for global approval of renaming
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
if  ( $b_Interactive )
    {
      print "In order to really rename the ", $Number,
            " files which can safely be renamed, type 'rename' :  ";
      $_ = <STDIN>;
      sleep 1;                       # Gives time to PERL to handle interrupts
      if  ( not m/^rename$/i )
          { exit 1 }
    }
else
    { print $Number, " files will be renamed\n\n" }

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#  Rename accented file names sorted descending by name size
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
$Number  = 0;
my $Move = join('  ', @Move);

for  ( sort {length($b) <=> length($a)} keys %News )
{
  $ErrorMessage = &OutputAndErrorFromCommand(@Move, $_, $News{$_});
  if  ( $? == 0 )
      { $Number++ }
  else
      { print "\n$Move  $Q$_$Q\n", (' ' x length($Move)),
        "  $Q$News{$_}$Q\n", ('*' x length($Move)), "  $ErrorMessage\n" }
}
print "\n$Number files have been successfully renamed\n";

__END__
`````

Comment: User 'nobi' was right: There still were problems with my $AccentedChars string. I am very happy that my consistency check on 'tr' permitted my script to stop before performing horrible renaming. I do NOT have a place to safely upload my original PERL script, so I fixed the version above, and I tested it successfully. Therefore, I hope that the version above is now good. Please test it.

Comment: Hi 'medien-auditiv'.
My script trusts the value of your 'LANG' environment variable.
Your error message looks weird, because line 390 of my script prints it completely as UTF8, and the 'ö' of 'öäß-testfolder' is correctly displayed using UTF-8, but the 'ö' of 'möglich' looks as displayed using ISO-8859-1 :
*** ls: Zugriff auf öäß-testfolder nicht mÃ¶glich: No such file or directory
Could you verify that the output of the 'locale' command is consistent ?
Besides, my mail provider is free.fr, my account there is eurbah, und ich verstehe ein wenig Deutsch. MFG.

Comment: Today's version of my PERL script has greatly improved robustness, and should now correctly :
- take into account file names with legacy and UTF-8 characters, file names containing quotes and file names beginning with dash.
- print error messages with the adequate encoding.
Besides, it now converts all accented characters of CP 1250 (Central European), CP 1252 (Western European), CP 1254 (Turkish) and CP 1257 (Baltic).
Please test it.

Comment: I keep getting a "cannot find file" error: http://pastebin.com/sTQ1tPc1 (environment: Windows 7 x64 with ActivePerl x64 5.18.1.1800)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this batch to rename folders and seems to work fine so far...
In my case codepage is 1252, yours might be different.

```
mode con codepage select=1252
@echo off
Setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
::folder only (/D option)
for /R /D %%d in (*) do (

set an=%%~nd
set bn=!an:.=_!
set cn=!bn:-=_!
set dn=!cn: =_!
set en=!dn:Á=A!
set fn=!en:É=E!
set gn=!fn:Í=I!
set hn=!gn:Ó=O!
set in=!hn:Ú=U!
set jn=!in:Ü=U!
set kn=!jn:á=a!
set ln=!kn:é=e!
set mn=!ln:í=i!
set nn=!mn:ó=o!
set on=!nn:ú=u!
set pn=!on:ü=u!
set qn=!pn:Ñ=N!
set zn=!on:ñ=n!

set ax=%%~xd
set bx=!ax:.=_!
set cx=!bx:-=_!
set dx=!cx: =_!
set bx=!ax:.=_!
set cx=!bx:-=_!
set dx=!cx: =_!
set ex=!dx:Á=A!
set fx=!ex:É=E!
set gx=!fx:Í=I!
set hx=!gx:Ó=O!
set ix=!hx:Ú=U!
set jx=!ix:Ü=U!
set kx=!jx:á=a!
set lx=!kx:é=e!
set mx=!lx:í=i!
set nx=!mx:ó=o!
set ox=!nx:ú=u!
set px=!ox:ü=u!
set qx=!px:Ñ=N!
set zx=!ox:ñ=n!


if [!an!]==[] (set zn=)
if [!ax!]==[] (set zx=)

set newname=!zn!!zx!

if /i not [%%~nd%%~xd]==[!newname!] rename "%%d" !newname!

)

endlocal

pause
```