# Windows batch script which removes text in brackets from filenames?

Tags: windows, shell, scripting, vbscript, batch-file

I have a bunch of files in a folder which I'd like to copy and rename via a .bat or .vbs script (or similar). The files are named as such:

```
ABC-DE-(XXX)SomeNameHere.dat
```

I'd like to **copy** the files and rename them, removing the (XXX) part, leaving simply:

```
ABC-DE-SomeNameHere.dat
```

There is a kind-of similar question answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261515/batch-file-script-to-remove-special-characters-from-filenames-windows) but I couldn't modify it to work for the above filename pattern, and also it simply renames the files, doesn't copy them.

Any help is much appreciated! Many thanks.

---

**Edit:** posting (*terrible!*) code below. Probably best to ignore this ;_;

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR %%F IN ("ABC-DE-(*)*.dat") DO CALL :process "%%F"
GOTO :EOF

:process
SET oldname=%1
SET "newname=%~nx1"
SET "newname=%newname:*] =%"
RENAME %oldname% "%newname%"
```

Comment: Show us the code you have written and tell us what errors you are getting...then we can help you make it work.

Comment: @aphoria Done, but it's terribly useless. My batch scripting knowledge is very basic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are too hard on yourself. Your code was closer than you think.

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR %%F IN ("ABC-DE-(*)*.dat") DO CALL :process "%%F"
GOTO :EOF

:process
SET oldname=%1
SET "newname=%~nx1"
SET "newname=%newname:*)=ABC-DE-%"
RENAME %oldname% "%newname%"
```

The above can be shortened

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR %%F IN ("ABC-DE-(*)*.dat") DO CALL :process "%%F"
GOTO :EOF

:process
SET "name=%~nx1"
REN %1 "%name:*)=ABC-DE-%"
```

You can eliminate the need for a CALL by using delayed expansion

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR %%F IN ("ABC-DE-(*)*.dat") do (
  SET name=%%~nxF
  REN "%%F" "!name:*)=ABC-DE-!"
)
```

The above delayed expansion solution is more efficient than using CALL, but it will fail if the file name contains `!` because the %%F expansion will be corrupted by the delayed expansion. This can be solved by toggling delayed expansion on and off within the loop.

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR %%F IN ("ABC-DE-(*)*.dat") do (
  SET oldName=%%F
  SET newName=%%~nxF
  SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
  REN "!oldName!" "!newName:*)=ABC-DE-!"
  ENDLOCAL
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your file naming pattern is consistent, you can use this:

```
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=)(" %%a in ('dir /b') do @rename "%%a(%%b)%%c" "%%a-%%c"
```

Comment: 1) Safer to use `"tokens=12*"`  2) Use `'dir /b "ABC-DE-(\*)\*.dat"'`  3) Remove `-` from last argument of rename command.

Comment: Mmmm.  1) Disagree. Not sure why this is safer if you know your parsed raw string will become three variables.Makes it overly complex.  2) Disagree. Ok for production - but for concept, makes it unnecessarily complex. 3) Agree - I used it for my test to improve readability, and should have removed it.

Comment: Point 1 - Part of the file name will be truncated if you use "tokens=1-3" and the file name happens to contain two or more parentheses pairs. I realize you prefaced your solution with "if your file naming pattern is consistent". But less harm is done if accidently run on file(s) with multiple parens. And I don't see how "tokens=12*" is more complex than "tokens=1-3"?