# Batch Rename by Replace substring

Tags: batch-file, replace, substring, rename

Hello :) when a friend give you a mp3 file, most often, the title is named that way: "avenged_sevenfold_-_buried_alive.mp3". i want to make a script which permit me to rename every file and folder of current repertoryby replacing "_" by " "(space). this is very long to rename each file manually; my script is here:

```
@echo off
title Merci qui ?
:debut
echo do you want to rename every files/foldes by replacing "_" by " "? (y/n)
set /p choix=


if %choix%==y (
goto renomage)

if %choix%==n (
goto end)

goto debut

:renomage

set /a x=1 :pointeur de fichier

set /a compteurA=0
set /a compteurB=0
for /f %%a in ('dir /b /a:-d *.*') do set /a compteurA+=1   
for /f %%a in ('dir /b /a:d *.*') do set /a compteurB+=1
echo %compteurA% fichiers %compteurB% dossiers
set /a n=compteurA+compteurB

echo number of folder/files batch included %n%


:while1 
if %x% GTR %n% goto prochain1 

set Strin=???name?ofthe?dossier?number?x?????????????
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=[,]" %%A in ('"%comspec% /u /c echo:%Strin%|more|find /n /v """') do          `set /a l=%%A-4`
echo Le nom contient %l% lettres.

:leftspace

set Strin=%Strin:_= %

set str=%Strin:~0,1%

if %str% EQU " "( 
set Strin=%Strin:~1,%l%-1%
goto leftspace)


SET /A x +=1
goto while1
:prochain1
echo Success ! (or not) 
pause
:end
```

i just need help for this line:

```
set Strin=???name?ofthe?dossier?number?x?????????????
```

otherwise the rest should be ok. if you have some critics or something, go on =)

Comment: If you are simply interested in renaming mp3 files (and not specifically in writing a program for doing it), there are a lot of programs for managing music collections. Have a look at [Picard](https://musicbrainz.org/doc/MusicBrainz_Picard)

Comment: no ^^ im interested by a program in batch ; rename music was just an Excuse for programing something :p

Comment: possible duplicate of [Batch file script to remove special characters from filenames (Windows)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/261515/batch-file-script-to-remove-special-characters-from-filenames-windows)

Answer (score 2):

This solution is reposted from [How to Batch Rename Files in Windows: 4 Ways to Rename Multiple Files](http://www.howtogeek.com/111859/how-to-batch-rename-files-in-windows-4-ways-to-rename-multiple-files/) by Chris Hoffman

PowerShell offers much more flexibility for renaming files in a command-line environment. Using PowerShell, you can pipe the output of one command – known as a “commandlet” in PowerShell terms — to another command, just like you can on Linux and other UNIX-like systems.

[image: Open PowerShell ISE]

First of all, open Powershell ISE and then navigate to the directory (folder) that has the files and folders you'd like to rename by using this command:

```
cd "C:\your\directory\"
```

[image: Navigate to your folder]

The two important commands you’ll need are Dir, which lists the files in the current directory, and Rename-Item, which renames an item (a file, in this case). Pipe the output of Dir to Rename-Item and you’re in business.

After you launch PowerShell ISE, use the cd command to enter the directory containing your files. You should put the files in their own directory so you don’t accidentally rename other files.

For example, let’s say we don’t want the underscore character in our file names – we’d rather have a space instead.

The following command lists the files in the current directory and pipes the list to Rename-Item. Rename-Item replaces each underscore character with a space.

```
Dir | Rename-Item –NewName { $_.name –replace "_"," " }
```

Replace the "`_`" and "" parts of the command to replace other characters in file names.

Consult [Microsoft’s documentation on the Rename-Item commandlet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315353.aspx) if you want  help performing other, more advanced operations.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
FOR %%f IN (ad a-d ) DO FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
  'dir /b /s /%%f "%sourcedir%\*" '
  ) DO CALL :chgnam %%a

GOTO :EOF

:chgnam
SET "name=%*"
SET "newname=%name:_= %"
IF "%newname%" neq "%name%" ECHO REN "%name%" "%newname%"

GOTO :eof
```

The required REN commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(REN` to `REN` to actually rename the files and directories. Directories are renamed first.

You will need to change `sourcedir` to point to your required directory. All files and directories in the tree which contain the `_` would be renamed - if it's possible to rename them.

[revised and corrected version]

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
PUSHD "%sourcedir%"
FOR %%f IN (ad a-d ) DO FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
  'dir /b /s /%%f "%sourcedir%\*" '
  ) DO CALL :chgnam "%%a" "%%~nxa"
POPD

GOTO :EOF

:chgnam
SET "name=%~2"
SET "newname=%name:_-_=-%"
SET "newname=%newname:_= %"
IF "%newname%" neq "%name%" ECHO(REN "%~1" "%newname%"

GOTO :eof
```

The original version would show incorrect `ren` syntax (the new-name may not contain a path)

If you want to run on the current directory, simply set the value of `sourcedir` to a single dot.

Comment: Ty for your answer Magoo :) , i just want to avoir the need of indicate the sourcedir by the way, i mean, i dont need to indicate it cause i just want that my Script works for this current Folder. (where my .bat is placed)

Comment: i just tried with a directory, the thing is that `%name%` will stock "C:\Users\Dude\Desktop\new folder" but with that `SET "newname=%name:_= %"` it will rename all the directory and if we have `c:\new_folder\martin_garix.mp3` it will be replace by `c:\new folder\martin garix.mp3` (new_folder => new folder) its a problem ^^

Comment: Use `set "sourcedir=."` to execute the batch on the current directory. That way, the batch can be located in any directory on the **PATH** - it doesn't have to ve in the current directory; just `cd` to the directory you wish to process and enter the batch name to process *this* directory.