# Need a batch\command to replace file names with special characters

Tags: batch-file, filenames

Need a batch\command to replace file names with special characters.

Example :

I have number of file names similar to “997-174 Change Request #2.doc”. I wish to rename such files to “997-174 Change Request 2.doc” at one shot (preferably in multiple folders).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/261515/batch-file-script-to-remove-special-characters-from-filenames-windows

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo on
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

echo renaming files in %1
for %%A in (%1\*) do (

    set B="%%~nA"
    echo "~nB"
    set B=!B:#=!
    echo renaming "%%~nA"
    echo       to !B!  
    ren "%%A" !B!.doc

)
pause
```