# rename the characters "=" and "!"

Tags: batch-file

I ask for your help. I found this code on the net that is working, but I can't run the characters "=" and "!". Can they help?
[Batch file script to remove special characters from filenames (Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261515/batch-file-script-to-remove-special-characters-from-filenames-windows/261553#261553)

```bat
mode con codepage select=1252
@echo off
Setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
::folder only (/D option)
for /R /D %%d in (*) do (

set an=%%~nd
set bn=!an: =_!
set cn=!bn:%%=_!
set dn=!cn:%#=_!
set en=!dn:%$=_!
set fn=!en:^&=_!
set gn=!fn:^'=_!
set hn=!gn:^€=_!
set in=!hn:^@=_!
set jn=!in:^£=_!
set kn=!jn:^§=_!
set ln=!kn:"!"=_!
set zn=!ln:"="=_!

set ax=%%~xd
set bx=!ax: =_!
set cx=!bx:%%=_!
set dx=!cx:%#=_!
set ex=!dx:%$=_!
set fx=!ex:^&=_!
set gx=!fx:^'=_!
set hx=!gx:^€=_!
set ix=!hx:^@=_!
set jx=!ix:^£=_!
set kx=!jx:^§=_!
set lx=!kx:"!"=_!
set zx=!lx:"="=_!

if [!an!]==[] (set zn=)
if [!ax!]==[] (set zx=)

set newname=!zn!!zx!

if /i not [%%~nd%%~xd]==[!newname!] rename "%%d" !newname!

)

endlocal
```

Comment: I'd be interested to know what you think the caret, `^`, and percent, `%` characters are supposed to mean? I would suggest that many of the lines you've included will not work as you think they should!

Comment: as said above, if you're new then it's better to learn powershell instead. Just avoid all the legacies and intricacies of cmd. If cmd is a must then [tag:jrepl] is a much better choice. Internally it still calls to jscript because cmd isn't suitable for this

Answer (score 1):

Search&replace of an exclamation mark can only be done with percent expansion.

```
set "tmp=%tmp:^!=_%"  ** In case of Deleayed Expansion enabled
set "tmp=%tmp:!=_%"   ** In case of Deleayed Expansion disabled
```

But an equal sign can't be part of the search expression.
You could still search/replace it by examine each single character in a string.

Answer (score 1):

As jeb said in his answer, you cannot find/replace `=` with variable expansion. So pure batch is not a good option for you.

Your task becomes trivial if you use [JREN.BAT](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6081) - a hybrid JScript/batch script for renaming files or directories using regular expressions. It runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward. No 3rd party exe or dll is required.

From the command line:

```
C:\>chcp 1252
Active code page: 1252

C:\>jren "[ %#$&'€@£§!=]" "_" /d /s
```

Or from a batch file

```
@echo off
chcp 1252
call jren "[ %%%%#$&'€@£§!=]" "_" /d /s
```

Note that within the batch file the `%` must be escaped twice as `%%%%` due to the `CALL` statement. `CALL` must be used because `JREN` itself is a batch script.